# Scroll down to the element (ajax loaded content) in Fancybox window

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-selectors, fancybox

Here is the problem. I load content by custom ajax call, if I get successful response I open fancybox window with it. There is a form submiting it's data via another ajax call. If form is valid, then I need to scroll down to element with id which exists only when the form is valid. Usually just run the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var target = $('#buttons');
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 2000);
 });
 </script>
```

But it does not work within Fancybox or I am doing something wrong. I have been working on this far too long. Some help will be appreciated. I apologize for my English. :D

Comment: does it throw any error in the console

Comment: No errors at all. And if (target.length > 0) returns true.

Comment: Also when I am loading lot of content then scrolling is working but in a wrong way. It's scrolling to the bottom of a page, not bottom of fancybox div with it's own scrollabrs. This div contatins table with about 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$('#buttons').length` before scrolling, value must **be > 0**

Possible element is not created when you want use `scrollTop`

Check your browser console on errors.

For scrolling I use this jquery plugin, helpful stuff

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html